# Change class with data-target

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried this:

```js
$(".font").click(function() {
  var target = $($(this).data("target"));
  $("#text").addClass(target);
})
```

```css
.pap {
  font-family: Papyrus;
}

.ar {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.hel {
  font-family: Helvetica,
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="font" data-target=".pap">Papyrus</button>
<button class="font" data-target=".ar">Arial</button>
<button class="font" data-target=".hel">Helvetica</button>

<div id="text" class="ar">Text</div>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work to change the classes by clicking a button. Is it just a little mistake or does this logic not work at all?

Comment: why are you passing `target` - a jquery object into `addClass`?

Comment: @DanielA.White The document will include in the end around 30 different font files. By clicking buttons, different areas should change. I think data-target is the smoothest way to keep control over the whole thing. But I don't understand what's wrong in my code.

Comment: use `console.log(target)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems:

1. Wrapping `$(this).data("target")`,
2. Including class selector `.` in `target` dataset: `data-target=".pap"`,
3. Adding class rather than replacing class:

```js
$(".font").click(function() {
  var target = $(this).data("target"); // no double $ wrap
  
  // replace class because the first class listed takes precedence
  $("#text").attr('class', target);
})
```

```css
.pap {
  font-family: Papyrus;
}

.ar {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.hel {
  font-family: Helvetica,
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- notice no "dot" classname -->
<button class="font" data-target="pap">Papyrus</button>
<button class="font" data-target="ar">Arial</button>
<button class="font" data-target="hel">Helvetica</button>

<div id="text" class="ar">Text</div>
```